# failed to upload when uploading a image with eajaxupload

Tags: yii

I am using the eajaxupload extension for uploading a file, every time when i am uploading it is getting that image failed ex     Tulips.jpg0.6MBFailed can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

You will need to post some code if anyone is going to help you properly. But anyway, here are some things to keep in mind when uploading files:

**Make sure the path is correct**

Make sure that the path to the directory in which you want to store the file exists. Next, make sure you are pointing to it correctly. A great thing to use is `getcwd()`, for example:

```
$path = getcwd()."/uploads";
```

**Make sure the filename is valid**

Often you will end up using variables for file names. If you are havning an issue, make sure that the value of the variable used for the filename actually has a value, for example:

```
$filename = $model->id.".".$model->image_type;
echo $filename; // myimage.jpg
```

**Make sure you are not exceeding you max file upload size**

Often, you will have an issue where the file you are uploading is greater than your maximum file upload size. You can set the max file upload size in your PHP ini file:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: Adore your patience in answering such a clumsy question